# How To Get Promo Code Value

Tags: expresso-store, ee2, checkout, discounts

I am displaying a promo code that the user submits by using `{promo_code}`, but now I also want to display the '*base discount*' value for the promo code. I tried to use `{promo_code_value}`, but this seems to be blank even though the R100 value of the promo code is reflected in the `{order_discount}` tag.

Any other suggestions on what I could try?

Comment: Just for some more info for someone else maybe: This seems to be a bug with Expresso Store at the moment. The {promo_code_value} tag is hardcoded as NULL, so that the tag parses, but always gives you an empty value.

Comment: I thought that must be a bug..

Answer (score 1):

The tag {order_discount} should give you the amount of money that's being discounted from the customers cart?

This will be formatted for currency, if you just want it as a numeric value, simply use {order_discount_val}.

You have:

- {order_subtotal} (The amount before the discount)
- {order_discount} (The amount of the discount being applied)
- {order_total} (The total after the discount has been applied and after tax/shipping).

Or have I misinterpreted the question?

Comment: Hey, thanks. This makes sense. My problem is getting the value of only the promo code and not any other discounts. I want to display the value of that specific promo code though.